# Spanish student travelling to Ypres holding only a Spanish ID Card and no passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration

We have a student with a Spanish ID card travelling to Ypres through Lille and back again with a school party.

Could you please let me know what information to take with us to prove that this student has exited the UK so that we have a carefree journey back from Ypres to the UK.  He does not own a British Passport.

Comment: What's your concern here? Is this student a minor? By “Spanish ID card”, do you mean the *documento nacional de identidad* issued to Spanish citizens? In this context, it is in almost every respects equivalent to a Spanish or British passport and Spanish citizens do not need anything else to either leave or (re)enter the UK or Belgium.

Answer (score 1):

How did he get into the UK in the first place, if he doesn't own a British passport?

Following site claims that you don't need a visa to go to the UK if you hold a (Spanish) national ID card:

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/spain

Does this answer your question? Because otherwise I would need some more information.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an actual answer. It's also incorrect that you need a Spanish *passport* to enter the UK. What the website should say (or perhaps already implies) is that you don't a visa if you have Spanish *citizenship*. But a passport is not the only valid way to establish that. Even if there are no general British ID card scheme, being a EU member, the UK is committed to recognizing national ID cards from other EU countries (and I have visited in the past with no issue using only my ID card).

Comment: @Relaxed Perhaps it was indeed more appropriate as a comment. I got ID card and passport mixed up, because of the translation from Dutch, my bad. Thanks for correcting me.